# How did they fix the footer to the bottom with the page scrolling on top?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, footer

I found a really cool website that has a fixed footer and the page scrolls on top. I can't figure out how they did this?  Take a lokk at their website:  http://sidigital.co/

Is this a script or CSS?

Comment: Right click -> inspect element or F12.  The animation uses js.

Comment: I did and I found basic CSS.  Still confused.

Comment: It has to be scripted.

Comment: "Hi, how does this script work? Please click on this link which, let's be honest, might go ANYWHERE and download ANYTHING onto your computer, because I can't be bothered to search the code myself." No, thank you.

Comment: It could be done with some variation `position: fixed` pretty easily.

Answer (score 3):

Its CSS.  The important part is here.  Note that the body has a padding-bottom that is the height of the footer. That way, the footer isn't overlapping the body content.  Then, the footer's height is explicit and its positioned at the bottom of the page.  A good tutorial on this is here http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

```
body {
padding-bottom: 453px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.footer {
height: 475px;
position: relative;
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad.  Makes sense.  Appreciate it.

Comment: To the down voters above, if he knew the best way to find the answer, then he wouldn't have to ask now would he?  I think its generally good practice to give people the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Brad If he'd typed his general question into Google instead, he would have found dozens of guides, answers and tutorials. StackOverflow is a community of programmers, not librarians.

Comment: As part of a community of programmers and not as a community of tight-asses Brad answered the gentlemen's simple question.  I would have done the same.  Upvote for the comment and the answer.

Comment: This is a community of _helpful_ programmers. This had some evidence of prior effort and seemed to genuinely be interested in how something worked, not for it to be "coded for them." Not really worthy of an upvote but an answerable question nonetheless.

Comment: I developed this site, I can confirm this is correct :) Wrote a blog post about how some of the other things were achieved if you wanted to know OP http://sidigital.co/blog/the-design-and-build-of-the-si-digital-website